# Is it possible to decrement a variable in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wanting to decrement a variable in a MySQL table by one everytime an UPDATE query is ran.

What I have is this, which isn't working:

`UPDATE forum SET replys = reply--  WHERE fid = '$id'`

Is this possible in any way, or am I going to have to run a SELECT and get the value first, decrement it, and then insert the new value into the UPDATE query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
UPDATE forum SET replys = reply - 1 WHERE fid = '$id'
```

Comment: sometimes it's so simple you just want to yell... thanks, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `replys - 1`?

Answer (score 6):

of course:

```
UPDATE forum SET replies=replies-1 WHERE fid = ?
```